# Maven Integration for Eclipse Juno Issue on Mac Lion OS

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

How do I get to see Dependencies | Reporting etc

[image]

Even after installing the Maven Plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace...It looks like this...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like some other xml editor is getting preference over the pom specific editor. This happens now and then depending on what else you have installed (e.g. the Android ADT also grabs that sometimes wrongly for pom.xml files).

If you encounter this problem just right click on the pom.xml file in the Package Explorer and select Open With - Maven POM Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed M2E plugin for Eclipse??

```
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse
```

You can find it in Eclipse MarketPlace.

Comment: @Appsheriff can you check in the preferences of the eclipse --> maven -->user interface -->"Open XML page in the POM editor by default" checkbox is ticked or not

Comment: you have to restart your eclipse for that